# If $[[x,y],z]=1$, then $[x,yz]=[x,y][x,z]$ and $[xy,z]=[x,z][y,z]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Question:**

If $[[x,y],z]=1$ holds in a group $G$, then show that  $[x,yz]=[x,y][x,z]$ and $[xy,z]=[x,z][y,z]$ also hold in $G$.

**Answer**

I showed earlier that $[x,yz]=[x,y]y[x,z]y^{-1}$. Thus, in order for the first equality to be true $y$ must commute with $[x,z]$ but I don't see how this follow from the given assumption. Thanks in advance...

Comment: "$[[x,y],z]$ holds in $G$" means for *all* $x,y,z\in G$. In particular, $[[x,z],y]=1$ also holds.

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot!